# ERROR! This task 'import_playbook' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules

Tags: ansible

Please find below my Ansible directory structure.

```
├── inventories
│   ├── ansible_host
│   └── group_vars
│       ├── all
│       └── vars
├── plays
│   ├── 01_recovery.yml
├── restore_all.yml
└── roles
    ├── 01_recovery_lostMaster
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── files
    │   ├── handlers
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── meta
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── tasks
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── tests
    │   │   ├── inventory
    │   │   └── test.yml
    │   └── vars
    │       └── main.yml
    ├── remove_failed_master
    │   ├── defaults
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── files
    │   ├── handlers
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── meta
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── tasks
    │   │   └── main.yml
    │   ├── templates
    │   ├── tests
    │   │   ├── inventory
    │   │   └── test.yml
    │   └── vars
    │       └── main.yml
```

1) Parent Playbook book: `restore_all.yml`

```
- name: Demo of restore plan
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False

  vars_prompt:
    - name: "Action"
      prompt: |
        - Choose Action ?
        - 1] Action 1
        - 2] Action 2
        - Please select anyone action
      private: no

  tasks:

    - name: Action 1 Details
      when: Action == "1"
      import_playbook: plays/01_recovery.yml

    - name: Action 2 Details
      when: Action == "2"
      import_playbook: plays/02_recovery.yml
```

2) `01_recovery.yml`

```
---
- name: Restore role
  hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - { role: restore/roles/01_recovery_lostMaster, tags: ['01_recovery_lostMaster'] }

- name: remove failed master
  hosts: master-01
  become: true
  roles:
    - { role: restore/roles/remove_failed_master, tags: ['remove_failed_master'] }
```

Finally, when I run a playbook using the import_playbook, I get the below error.

```
[root@api localhost]# ansible-playbook restore_all.yml -e "host=localhost"
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! this task 'import_playbook' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: shell, win_shell, include_vars, add_host, raw, include_role, meta, set_fact, include, import_tasks, script, import_role, include_tasks, group_by, command, win_command
```

The error appears to be in `'/home/ec2-user/restore/restore_all.yml': line 20, column 7`, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

```
- name: Action 1 Details
  ^ here
```

And, also I tried with import_tasks, it gave me the below error:

```
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'
ERROR! conflicting action statements: hosts, roles
```

Please can you help to solve my issue from the above-provided scenario?

restore_all.yml --> Import another playbook --> Run one role in localhost and another role in another host.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please take some time to edit your question and format it correctly (code, output, error messages....).

Comment: So what's the tech. stack you are using?

Answer (score 9):

As shown in [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#importing-playbooks), you cannot use `import_playbook:` in a `tasks:` context, only at the top level

So, what you will want with your choose-your-own-adventure setup there is to either `include_tasks:` based on the variable, so long as all tasks apply to the same hosts, or dynamically build up hosts using [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/add_host_module.html) based on the vars if the playbooks target different ones, but always including both playbooks (and only one of them will run based on the outcome of `add_host:`)